# Powermail 2.0 in TYPO3

Tags: typo3

Im trying powermail 2.0 in a TYPO3 4.7, for the first time, and I'm getting this error message in frontend:

> The default controller can not be determined. Please check for Tx_Extbase_Utility_Extension::configurePlugin() in your ext_localconf.php.

What am I missing? I already inserted one static template.

Comment: Did you include all required TS from extension ?

Comment: If you mean about dependencies, there was no conflict message during installation

Comment: I mean 'Include static from extension' in your main TS template.

Comment: In the template I included "Main Template (powermail)"

Comment: Make sure that you cleared all caches etc, etc. The problem _should not occure_ ...

Comment: Caches are cleared, and error keeps coming :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had the same problem!
i reviewed the form i created and found that somehow the checkbox for custom variable name in an input field was checked and the value was empty {}.

so somehow that crooked the whole plugin . now it works flawless!

greets from austria
Andy