# Getting following error in powermail 2.0, What am i missing in configuration?

Tags: php, email, typo3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Powermail 2.0 in TYPO3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11566021/powermail-2-0-in-typo3)

```
The default controller can not be determined. Please check for Tx_Extbase_Utility_Extension::configurePlugin() in your ext_localconf.php.
```

Comment: What can be done to resolved this ?

Answer (score 0):

Open CheckBe.html file overthere

```
<f:form action="checkBe" controller="List"> is defined
```

Replace this code with

```
<f:form action="checkBe" controller="Module">
```

It's because there is no list action inbuilt in powermail extension.